# Wrong pip install modules

Tags: python, module, sys

After several installations in different version of python and add of external modules through
`pip install <module>`  on `Win10` that run smoothly. From a couple of days ago I was reinstalling `Spyder IDE` but I don't think might be related to its installation, when installing some basic modules like: `sklearn, scikit-learn or Polars..` or whatever other not preinstalled in python, when then I exec my script.py both through Spyder or sys command line, the system is not able to find any of those modules and return exception despite the module is `"Successful Installed"` and its directory is present in `"site-packages"`:

> C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Linguaggi\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\polars_*init*_.py:12: UserWarning: polars binary missing!
> warnings.warn("polars binary missing!")
>
> !next
> ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'
>
> ---
>
> Contents of C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Linguaggi\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\sklearn_*check_build:
> setup.py                  *check_build.cp37-win_amd64.pyd__init**.py
> **pycache**
>
> ---
>
> It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

I guess some setting were fuzzygly changed to let the system doesn't find such modules...Any idea of what happen ? ...and more important, how to fix it ?  thanks

I reinstalled python's distro and tryed to add the "site-packages" path as new system path where to pick up the modules

Comment: You really need to use virtual environments and WSL on Windows.  Especially if you are going to install multiple versions of python. See https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-setup-a-python-virtual-environment-on-windows-10/

Comment: ..I work with only 1 version of python and till couple of days ago the installation procedure/system works at once !!?